# I am trying to scrape a website with Node.js, but I got blocked from the website. How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-scraping, node-horseman

http://pslsource.com/buy_tennessee_titans_psl/

This is the website I'm trying to **scrape**. It has some tables with prices, and I can't access it through my Node app anymore (which is on Heroku). How can I re-access it again? Any proxies or other suggestions?

Here's the code as well:

```
var Horseman = require("node-horseman");

var h = new Horseman({timeout: 50000});

h.open("http://pslsource.com/buy_tennessee_titans_psl/")
.waitForSelector("body")
.text("body")
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

*Note: All credits will be paid to the original website, I won't claim the data as my own.*

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have been blocked from the site clearly shows that crawling the site is against the intention of the owners. You could "solve" this by using proxies and send requests to their APIs.

However, if crawling the site is in fact a legitimate action, then send an email to them and explain them why do you intend to crawl their site, convince them that your intentions are not against their interests. They might give you an export. If not, then do not try to extract data from there.

Comment: +1, and this kind of blocking often come when your crawler is not well behaved, e.g. Too many requests per second.